# Django-Rest-Framework Custom User not Hashing Password (Serializer Issue)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-serializer

I am trying to use token authentication, but it is not working due to my create user serializer not hashing the passwords. I am able to login with the superuser as that has a hashed password. Using rest_auth and rest_framework.authtoken. The user.set_password command is supposed to hash the password, so is there an issue with the prior code?

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only = True, style = {'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'id','username', 'password', 
            'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'
        )
        write_only_fields = ('password')
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            user = super().create(validated_data)
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return user
```

```
class CreateUserAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    """
    Create a new user.
    """
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        # Create a token that will be used for future auth
        token = Token.objects.create(user = serializer.instance)
        token_data = {"token": token.key}

        return Response(
            {**serializer.data, **token_data},
            status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            headers = headers
        )
```

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'url', 'username', 'email', 'groups', 'workflow_step',
            'first_name', 'last_name', 
            'birthdate',
            'address_street1', 'address_street2', 'address_city', 
            'address_state', 'address_postal_code', 'address_country', 'phone'
        )
```

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Application process
    workflow_step = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Basic information
    # first_name (in django.contrib.auth.models.User)
    # last_name (in django.contrib.auth.models.User)
    # email (in django.contrib.auth.models.User)

    # Advanced Information
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    address_street1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_street2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    address_state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address_postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    address_country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably too late, but for anyone who has this issue. you need to put the `create` function directly inside the serializer class, in your case you have it in the `Meta` subclass

The second thing you need to do is to use

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    user = super().create(validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

best of luck

Answer (score 1):

This works for me..try this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # <Your other UserSerializer stuff here>

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CreateUserSerializer.create` you're doing this:

```
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        ...
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
```

By the time you call `set_password` the `password`key has been removed from `validated_data`. You probably want to change the `set_password` line to this instead:

```
        user.set_password(password)
```

Comment: That still didn't fix the issue - passwords are still not hashed.

Comment: So a new user is created but their password field is empty? Or are you getting an error?

Comment: A new user is created, but the password field has the plaintext password and not the hashed password.

Comment: Are you using a custom user model?

Comment: Yes, I've added the UserSerializer and custom model to the original question as reference

Comment: In that case it looks like you've either overridden `set_password` somewhere, you're setting user.password directly somewhere after calling `set_password`, or one of your methods isn't being called. Probably time to step through a request using a debugger and see exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `make_passowrd` function in order of hashing it:

```py
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only = True, style = {'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            'id','username', 'password', 
            'email', 'first_name', 'last_name'
        )
        write_only_fields = ('password')
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            user = super().create(validated_data)
            user.set_password( make_password(validated_data['password']))
            user.save()
            return user
```

Read all about password managing [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers)

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the 'password' key before hashing it.
You need to change
`user.set_password(validated_data['password'])` this to
`user.set_password(password)` as you popped that from validated data and stored to password variable.

Answer (score 0):

Saving hashed password in Serializer using validated_data dict doesnt work, it saves password in plain text even when make_password method is used.

I got this done by altering the value of password filed in view class itself and by using make_password method to hash the password before saving the Serializer...see the code below:

```
class PostAccountView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
# Comment the below parser to use this view via Postman, make sure parameters are added as form_data under body section in postman
# parser_classes = [FormParser]

queryset = Registration_Model.objects.all()
serializer_class = PostAccountSerializer

def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = PostAccountSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.validated_data["password"] = make_password(serializer.validated_data["password"])
        serializer.validated_data["confirm_password"] = make_password(serializer.validated_data["confirm_password"])
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```